# Java toArray() conversion for primitive arrays

Tags: java, collections

I have trouble understanding why the conversion to primitive array fails for a one dimensional array but works for the two dimensional case.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    List<Integer> oneD = List.of(1,2,3);
    int[] one = oneD.toArray(int[]::new); // error

    List<int[]> twoD = List.of(
            new int[]{1,2},
            new int[]{3,4}
            );

    int[][] two = twoD.toArray(int[][]::new); // works
}
```

I tried making my way through the documentation but of no avail. One thing I can see is that in the first case, since we are trying to convert from `Integer` to `int`, is what might be causing the error, and that the second case works fine since `int[]` would be an Object type.

An explanation with an example of how `toArray` works, especially for primitives would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, `Integer` is nothing like `int`. An `int[]` is not an `Object[]`.

Also, two dimensional arrays? You're mistaken; those do not exist. An `int[][]` is not a 2d-array of ints. It's a 1d array of int arrays. There is some light syntax sugar to let you write `int[][] x = new int[5][10];`, which is sugar for:

```
int[][] x = new int[5][];
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) x[i] = new int[10];
```

and that's nice and convenient, but under the hood it's not a 2D array; these do not exist. The 'component type' of `x.getClass()` is `int[].class - and then array can be 'disjointed' (you can have row 0 contain 5 cells, and row 1 contain 10 cells, i.e. you could write` x[1] = new int[20];` and this works fine.

That explains why the `twoD` example works.

To convert a `List<Integer>` to an `int[]`, write a for loop.

```
List<Integer> list = ...;
int[] arr = new int[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) arr[i] = list.get(i);
```

Comment: I am aware of how arrays work. Perhaps my lack in understanding arises from confusion around Objects and reference type(int[] here). I assumed that Collections only work for Object types and hence I said that int[] would be an Object. .Can you help clarify a bit around why the `twoD` example works

Comment: Because an `int[]` is an Object (`Object x = new int[10];` is legal java code), but an `int` is not (`Object x = 5;` does 'work', but only because that 5 is silently converted (autoboxed)). `.toArray()` can only convert to an array of some object type. Thus, `int[][]` is fine (that is an array of `int[]`, and `int[]` is an object), but `int[]` is not (that is an array of `int` which is not an object type).

Comment: Yes. This is what my presumption was, which is why I stated `int[]` as an object. I misread your answer wherein you stated `int[]` is not `Object[]` as `Object`. Thanks for your explanation, marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`toArray` cannot generate primitive arrays since `List`s can't contain primitive elements.

You can use `IntStream` to achieve the conversion without an explicit loop:

```
int[] one = oneD.stream ().mapToInt (Integer::intValue).toArray ();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had researched well into converting two and fro between primitives and collections. But understanding how it interprets `int[][]` was my point of confusion. Taking `int[]` as `T` and then writing `T[]` makes it a bit clear now why second example works. Still unsure why `int[]` is not an Object. I thought Java only has Primitives and Objects, wherein Objects are just references themselves

Comment: @arjunkhera `int[]` *is* an object. Its elements are not. Since `int[]` is an `Object`, `int[][]` also is an `Object[]` which is the reason why `toArray` works.